# Rolling Dice , P of rolling a six with 1 die vs P of rolling two same values using two dice

Tags: probability

If it`s true that the probability of rolling a six on one die is 1/6;
and that the probability of rolling two dice and getting same value on both is 1/6;

does that actually mean that both these events are equally likely?

If I`m making a bet with a friend , and he uses 1 die, while I use two. Can I say that he is just as likely of rolling a six, as I am of rolling two values that are the same?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Yes, assuming that fair dice are used.